# OroCRM Couldn't create new leads

Tags: symfony, orocrm

I'm using OroCRM and installed with all the basic configuration setup.
Everything works fine in my localhost, and I have set up the same on the server successfully too.

But i couldn't create new leads. When I tried to create new lead it's showing ***"500 Internal server error. The System is currently under maintenance and should be available in a few minutes."***

I have clear the cache and tried too, but same issue persist.

Any idea why it's showing like this ?

Any help would be appreciated.
Sorry for bad English.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By adding app_dev.php to you url you can see whats wrong.

> orocrm.com/app_dev.php

Comment: I did schedule sync in => System/Integrations/Manage Integrations after that go to check => System/Jobs  i getting message like There are no oro.messagequeue.job.entity_plural_label. what is how can i schedule my magnto data's?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we get this error if package installation gets failed and take the site to maintenance mode. I used following command to unlock the maintenance mode:
php app/console lexik:maintenance:unlock